# How to download artifacts in azure devops from a different repo into the current repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts, build-definition

I have written a azure pipeline named my-azure-pipelines.yml to download the artifacts published in a specific build.

I have used the following task in my pipeline to download the artifacts from a specific build.

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  displayName: 'Download Artifacts'
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: 'YourProjectName'  # Replace with your Azure DevOps project name
    **definition: 'YourBuildPipelineName'  # Replace with the name of your build pipeline**(error)
    buildId: 'YourBuildId'  # Specify the build ID you want to download artifacts from
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'YourArtifactName'  # Replace with the name of the published artifact
    downloadPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/DownloadedArtifacts'
```

I am getting error which says
##[error]Definition name xyz didn't correspond to a valid definition

I am not sure what a build definition is and how to find it. Appreciate if somebody explains

I was expecting that the artifacts would be downloaded but due to the error the artifact are not getting downloaded

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no** `definition` parameters for the task [DownloadBuildArtifacts@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-build-artifacts-v0?view=azure-pipelines).

To fix the error, you can

1. click on the `settings`(grey) link to simply pick the value for the parameters on the right side.
2. Then click `add` button, it will automatically override with correct values.

[image]

After fix, it should look like below:

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  displayName: 'Download Artifacts'
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '1b60f1ab-xxxx3c91a6'
    pipeline: '330'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'specific'
    buildId: '2488'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'YourArtifactName'
    downloadPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/DownloadedArtifacts'
```

In addition, if the artifact comes from `another` project, please go to `Project settings` -> Pipelines -> Settings -> **Toggle off** the option `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines`.

[image]

[image]

If the target build is in same project, the option above is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may open the build which you are trying to use as an artifact source. Then check `definitionId` in the URL.

[image]

Comment: but it is asking for build definition. I have provided the build id..

Comment: @kiranitagi `definition` and `buildId` are required when you use `buildType: 'specific'`. Check this document: [DownloadBuildArtifacts@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-build-artifacts-v0?view=azure-pipelines)